# How To Solve TemplateFileType.ClientSidePage Null Error in power Shell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want to create a modern page via share point online using power shell
put i get error in add template part as Template File Type not including ClientSidePage as in  code below

i tried the below code but get the following error

> Cannot convert argument "templateFileType", with value: "", for
>   "AddTemplateFile" to type
>   "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.TemplateFileType": "Cannot convert null
>   to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.TemplateFileType" due to
>   enumeration values that are not valid. Specify one of the following
>   enumeration values and try again. The possible enumeration values are
>   "StandardPage,WikiPage,FormPage"."

```
Add-Type -Path '*****************\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Add-Type -Path '*****************\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
Add-Type -Path '*****************\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll'


$SiteURL = "*****************/sites/*****************"
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$securePassword=ConvertTo-SecureString "*****************" -AsPlainText -Force
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials("*****************", $securePassword)



$pagesLibrary = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('Site Pages');
$ctx.Load($pagesLibrary);


$newPageitem = $pagesLibrary.RootFolder.Files.AddTemplateFile("/sites/*****************/SitePages/test.aspx",[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.TemplateFileType]::ClientSidePage).ListItemAllFields
                   $newPageitem["ContentTypeId"] = "0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C4118";
$newPageitem["Title"] = "Project Home";
$newPageitem["PageLayoutType"] = "RepostPage"
$newPageitem["CanvasContent1"] = "<div>test2019</div>";
$newPageitem.Update();
$ctx.Load($newPageitem);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

As in this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.templatefiletype

there is ClientSidePage to template type that will help me to create a modern page

Comment: I think you may be missing `Add-Type -Path '*****************\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Portable.dll'`

Comment: unfortunately same error exist after adding mentioned dll